# Downloading artifacts from coordinator forbidden

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am building a jar app with the gitlabci and after the build, the jar is sent to the next task with artifact.

```
Mavenbuild:artifact:
stage: mavenbuild
  image:
    name: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - mvn clean install -pl batch-o365 -am -q
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - batch-o365/app

Dockerbuild:ok:
  stage: dockerbuild
  image:
    name: ekino/docker-buildbox:latest-dind-aws
  dependencies:
    - Mavenbuild:artifact
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker build .
```

The artifact is well uploaded :

```
Uploading artifacts...
batch-o365/app: found 3 matching files             
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=11969 responseStatus=201 Created token=xxx
```

But when I tied to retrive it in the next task I have this error :

```
Downloading artifacts for Mavenbuild:artifact (11969)...
ERROR: Downloading artifacts from coordinator... forbidden  id=11969 responseStatus=403 Forbidden status=403 Forbidden token=xxx
FATAL: permission denied                           
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I already use artifacts on another projet from this gitlab server and it's working well.

Is someone here already has this issue with artifacts ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

We are using internal proxies and I forgot to exclude the gitlab URL.

With this modification :

```
Dockerbuild:ok:
  stage: dockerbuild
  image:
    name: ekino/docker-buildbox:latest-dind-aws
  variables:
    HTTP_PROXY: http://proxy:8000
    HTTPS_PROXY: http://proxy:8000
    NO_PROXY: 169.254.169.254,gitlab.xxx.com
```

Artifact is well retrived by the job.

```
Downloading artifacts for Mavenbuild:artifact (11989)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=11989 responseStatus=200 OK token=--xxx
```